# Missing git branch indicator at bottom of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, branch

This: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/media/vside-gitinteraction.png

I couldn't find a way to enable it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tools > Options > Environment > General

Tick "Show Status Bar"

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure your Visual Studio 2017 is up to date and that you have Git as your source control provider.

Directly from Visual Studio [website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017)

"I don't see the Add to Source Control button in the status bar.

A: The Add to Source Control button in the status bar ( Add to Source Control ) was added in Visual Studio 2017 (it was Publish in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and later) and will only appear when you have Git as your source control provider. If your code is already in a Git repo, you won't see the Add to Source Control button in the status bar, but the status of the current branch in your local repo instead."

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see "Add to source control" either.  It's like the toolbar is just missing.  I already have a git repository that I am working with through TFS

Comment: Git is your selected option in  Visual Studio Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in selection?

Comment: You're suppose to at least see "Add to source control" then when you have one selected you'll see what you want

Comment: Yes, I have git selected.  Still don't see anything at the bottom

Comment: I found it!  Under Tools/Options/Environment/General, I had to tick "show status bar".  Thanks for your help

Comment: In VS2017, my status bar is showing and the aforementioned checkbox is checked. The status bar has a branch icon that, when clicked, shows me all my Git repo's branches. However, unlike VS2015, the status bar does not show the current branch. Is there a way to do that in VS2017?

Comment: Re: my comment above, I figured it out: Looks like VS2017 was tripped up by my loading the solution from a SUBST drive. Looks like VS2015 has the same problem with SUBST drives.

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was updating the vscode and restart.